# importing XML file to create/update nodes, relation nodes/users, and taxonomy terms (to several vocabularies)

Tags: nodes, users, taxonomy-terms, importing-exporting

Thanks for take time to read this question.

I want to import a XML file. XML content will create/update: nodes, relations nodes/users, and taxonomy terms (to several vocabularies) and his relation with nodes. I want to know, if is possible, your experiences and suggestions about this kind of requirements, or modules to resolve this, or if is best a custom code.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@rocketeerbkw's answer is good, but personally I find that a custom import script is the way to go.  The source for the [Wordpress Import](http://drupal.org/project/wordpress_import) module is a good starting point for how to do things, and there are lots of other articles on the web about creating nodes with code.

Based on experience doing this on several projects, I find that I get things done quicker with a custom import script, and that I can fine tune things better.

Make sure you also install [Backup and Migrate](http://drupal.org/project/backup_migrate) so you can quickly backup/restore your database as you work on the data import.

Comment: thanks for take time to answer. Yes, I think that a custom script can be very felxible. Also I will review the recomendations of rocketeerbkw.

Comment: I have tried and to me this way is more flexible.

Answer (score 2):

The [migrate](http://drupal.org/project/migrate) and [migrate extras](http://drupal.org/project/migrate_extras) modules are your best friend for this (for Drupal 6 and 7).

The downside is all configuration is done in PHP Classes so you must have a reasonable amount of knowledge about them.

The upside is the documentation. The migrate module comes with an excellent example module that has examples for importing taxonomy, users, nodes + comments, files and roles from a SQL database and XML (it can also import from CSV, JSON and more but is not part of example module)

If you're looking for a nice UI to handle all this, migrate is not for you. You won't find anything else as flexible and full featured though.

Comment: Hi rocketeerbkw, thanks for your recomendation, I will review your suggestions (migrate and migrate extras).